# Shouldn't we improve the text below?

Tags: soporte

[image]

Shouldn't we improve the text in the textbox? Right now, it implies you earn ten points when it actually means need ten points in order to do that.

**You need 10 reputation points to answer this question.**

Answer (score 3):

With my non-native eyes, I interpret "Earn ten points in order to answer this question" as "you need to earn ten points to be able to answer this question". This is emphasized by the word "requirement" afterwards. In any case, we moderators cannot change this text. Such changes should be proposed on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, but there is still ambiguity. Removing the ambiguity is the best way to go: You need 10 points to answer this question. I will go the main Meta.

Comment: They wrote it like that ("earn...") because they want to make it clear that the association bonus does not count. So maybe a better suggestion would be "You need to earn 10 points on this site (not counting the association bonus) to answer this question".

Comment: Wow, association bonus, there's another poor term. I don't want to argue about the English with you. But one OP got confused and I can see why. This is really  no big deal.